No such module SwiftMessages
When I try to build my code in Xcode, I get an error no such module SwiftMessages
Can someone help?
I have different configurations - Development and Production. Development builds but not Production.
My Podfile
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '15.1'

target 'test' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Minuteapp
  pod 'SwiftMessages'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'ApphudSDK'
  pod 'FittedSheets'
  pod 'ColorThiefSwift'
  pod "SwiftChart"
  pod 'SDWebImage'
  pod 'AQPlayer'
  pod 'STPopup'
  pod 'Toast-Swift'
  pod 'PaddingLabel'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'DeviceKit'
  pod 'PushNotifications'
  pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
  pod 'AmplitudeSwift', '~> 1.0.0'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 17.0'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 17.0'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 17.0'
  pod 'FBAudienceNetwork', '6.15.0'
end


post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'YES'
    end
  end
    installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
          project.targets.each do |target|
              target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                  config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '15.1'
               end
          end
   end
end

